# Getting 'invalid BigNumber' error value when trying to change state of variable via Input

Tags: reactjs, input

Trying to pass a value via a changed state of an input element into a variable:

```
const [voteIdMainnet, setVoteIdMainnet] = useState('');
```

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        setVoteIdMainnet({
          ...voteIdMainnet,
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        })
      }
```

```
 <div>
       <input
          type="number"
          className="HeroInputLarge"
          name="voteIdMainnet"
          value={voteIdMainnet.disputeId}
          onChange={handleChange}
                                        
        />
</div>
```

But getting the error:

> Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value",
> value={"voteIdMainnet":"1"}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT,
> version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Any ideas?

Essentially the goal is to input a number and have a variable's value (voteIdMainnet) get assigned accordingly. This is a parameter that feeds into a yes/no vote which was working fine before when you just hardcoded the variable's value like so:

```
const voteIdMainnet = 9;
```

figured all i need to do is change the state of that variable depending on the input and the rest should be fine as is...

Comment: What's the code for this function: setVoteIdMainnet  ?

Comment: not sure i understand, there is no code for 'setVoteIdMainnet' outside of what I have above. should there be? Also, I was able to fix the warning about the controlled input (edited code above)

Comment: there has to be? Where is it defined?

Comment: Im under the impression it's defined with: const [voteIdMainnet, setVoteIdMainnet] = useState('') where voteIdMainnet is also defined.

Comment: why are you calling it like a function then?

Comment: hmm not entirely sure, following example of this repo which seems to work fine (see line 60): https://github.com/tellor-io/fundAFeed/blob/18c97a16bfd9733845f920bd769756400f343321/src/components/Hero.js

Comment: Also, updated the error message to reflect the new changes i made.

Comment: @Rayn Don’t worry about the `setVoteIdMainnet` definition. It is a function, defined and returned by React’s `useState` hook. I would focus on the fact that `voteIdMainnet` is initialized as a string, but gets set to an object. And you have `…voteIdMainnet` when it’s initially a string.

Comment: In the working code you mention, the value was a number. Now you start with a string, and on update change it to an object. Try using `onChange={setVoteIdMainnet}` on the `input` element. But then you will have to explain what the `voteIdMainnet.disputeId` is expected to mean, since `voteIdMainnet` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your awesome feedback! I was able to have someone troubleshoot with me and here are the steps we took to resolve:

The error was actually happening at the onClick call which used the handleVote function (which I failed to post above):

```
const handleVote = async (bool) => {
    if (!data) return;

    let contract;
    let didAlreadyVote;

    if (data.chainId === 1) {
        contract = new ethers.Contract(
            data.tellorGovMainnet,
            TellorGovABI,
            Object.keys(signer) > 0 ? signer : data.signer
        );
        didAlreadyVote = await contract.didVote(
            voteIdMainnet,
            currAddr.length > 0 ? currAddr : data.currentAddress
        );
        if (!didAlreadyVote) {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                contract
                    .vote(voteIdMainnet, bool, false)
                    .then((res) => {
                        setLoading(false);
                        setTxnHash(res.hash);
                        setJustVoted(true);
                    })
...
```

I simply needed to format 'voteIdMainnet' to how the object was being set, which was 'voteIdMainnet.voteIdMainnet'.
Probably not the cleanest solution, but I think this is what I get from trying to copy code from something that works slightly differently.

Really appreciate all the feedback here as there's a lot of things I'll consider in my logic moving forward!